# If file name have extra dot getting exception in c#, Jet connection string template

Tags: c#

If file name has additional dot character like below:

**sample.data.csv**
next select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [sample.data.csv]
```

with connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\Data\"; Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;Format=Delimited;";
```

Getting below exception:

The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'sample

Comment: Is the project using WinForms? You can use `DllImportAttribute` and calling `kernel32.dll` library to convert current file name into short file name format (DOS-alike).

Comment: Yes, Project is using WPF, MVVM.

Comment: Is there any other solution?